# Como Obtener Datos por medio de AJAX a Base de Datos Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, json, wordpress

Solicito amablemente de su ayuda, necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos para mostrar informacion de una compañia, pero no logro regresar la informacion para que me la muestre en la cosola y posterior enviar a inputs, esto en wordpress. Tengo el siguiente Codigo JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    ('#tickerselect').change(function () {
        let selecticker = jQuery(this).val();
        
        $ticker = selecticker;

     //   alert($ticker);

        //La llamada AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url : "admin-ajax.php", //baseUrl is wordpress root url 
            type : 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
            action:'myAjaxFun',//this is must
            data1: $ticker,
            //.....
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Y tengo el siguiente codigo para ejecutan la llamada del JS.

```
    function myAjaxFun() {
    
        if ( isset($_POST) ) {
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $ticker = $_POST["ticker"];
        $table = $wpdb->prefix .'company';
        
        if($ticker){
           
            $query = "
            SELECT id_company, name, ticker, sector FROM $table WHERE id_company = $ticker
            ";
            $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
            $data = array();
    
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row
            }
        
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
        }
         die();
    }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myAjaxFun' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction', 'myAjaxFun');
```

Que podria estar ocacionando el error?  Deseo obtener el nombre y sector por medio del ID del select para mostrarlo en inputs.

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el error? ¿Qué ves en la consola?

Comment: Me sale este error <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected token &quot;}&quot; in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php</b> on line <b>229</b><br />
  Pero revisando el codigo se ve bien, y en la consola no devuelve ningun valor, el reglon 229 es el simbolo } que esta abajo de  $data[] = $row

Comment: Falta terminar esa línea con `;`, debe quedar así: **`$data[] = $row;`**

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo eh agregado y al parecer si hace la consulta porque en el Network/Response si me aparecen los datos, pero en la consola no me llega la informacion. Deseo mandar esa info a unos inputs.

Comment: Ya, pero es que tu código PHP es demasiado ingenuo. ¿Qué te asegura que hay conexión? ¿Qué te asegura que hay datos?  ¿Qué te asegura que la consulta SQL  no es errónea? No controlas nada de eso en tu código. Por otra parte, observa tu parámetro `data` en Ajax, has dado la clave `data1` al valor que mandas: `data1: $ticker`, en el `$_POST` debes usar el valor de la izquierda para encontrar los datos. Ponlo así: `ticker: $ticker` y debería funcionar, aunque deberías controlar errores en tu código Ajax.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda, estoy estudiando mucho este tema y reconozco todos mi errores, y aprecio mucho tu ayuda, esa parte del data1 si me di cuenta ya esta corregido. Yo se que mi codigo es ingenuo y debo perfeccionarlo en eso estoy. Ya solo me falta mostrar la info en el console.log

Comment: Si la consulta SQL trajera datos deberían mostrarse, pero como digo, hay casos no cubiertos en tu código PHP, como si no trajera filas. Deberías verificar eso, mandando un mensaje de que no hay filas, etc.